# Crash occurs on opening Appium.exe in windows

Tags: selenium, webdriver, appium

Unable to install Appium.exe in Windows machines for testing Android Native apps that use Selenium WebDriver API

```
1) Tried on different PCs
2) installed Microsoft .NET framework version 4.0
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything in the Event Viewer?

Comment: @Arran How to check anything in the Event Viewer? I am in Computer Management > Event Viewer

Comment: **Error 23-05-2013 19:39:23 .NET Runtime 1026 None**             I got this error in the Event Log

Comment: @Arran I also performed **Clear LOG** but no outcome; please suggest me what to do..

Comment: Application: Appium.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentNullException
Stack:
at System.IO.Path.Combine(System.String, System.String, System.String)
at Appium.MainWindow.MainForm._DetectAVDs()
at Appium.MainWindow.MainForm.<MainForm_Load>b__2()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue got fixed after opening emulator through AVD Manager.

If the emulator is not active then appium.exe fail to open.

[image]